# How to convert Python List into multiple lines with attaching numbering?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've one List like:-

```
List = ["a","b","c"]
```

I want to convert it like below:-

```
 1. a
 2. b
 3. c
```

How can I achieve this by using python?

Comment: Do you want to print it or convert it into dictionary like {"1": "a","2": "b","3":"c"}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use    `emerate()`

```
List = ["a","b","c"]

for i,j in enumerate (List,1):
    print('{}. {}'.format(i,j))
```

Comment: That is exactly like my answer

Comment: @Sujay I'm sorry if you were offended. 
I just wanted to explain another format method.

Comment: No, I am not offended, don't take it personally. It is just that duplicating answer leads no where. Only new and fresh answers are generally upvoted

Comment: @Sujay I'm slowly learning Stack Overflow. Thanks for the good advice.

Answer (score 4):

Use `enumerate`

```
List = ["a","b","c"]
for i,j in enumerate (List,1):
    print(f'{i}. {j}')
```

If you want to create a dictionary

```
List2={i:j for i, j in enumerate (List1,1)}
```

Comment: @manishsoni please accept the answer if it solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
List = ["a","b","c"]
for i in range(len(List)):
    print(f'{i+1}. {List[i]}')
```